# Is there a "complete" Hydrogen level spectrum diagram out there?

Tags: hydrogen

From basic quantum physics we know that the energy levels in Hydrogen are quantized, with the first steps being made with the Bohr model. Then, spin gets introduced, and we get spin-orbit coupling, and so on...

I was googling around and tried to find a nice diagram where all the possible energy level splittings (fine structure, hyperfine structure, etc.) are illustrated. The best thing I found so far is the illustration in [this article here](http://backreaction.blogspot.co.at/2007/12/hydrogen-spectrum-and-its-fine.html) (for some reason I get a 404 error on the direct picture link). But I wonder if a diagram could be found (or made) that also includes the Zeeman/Stark effect or other effects of a more advanced nature. I hope it's somewhat clear what I mean :)

Basically, what is the "best"/most detailed level scheme of Hydrogen that packs all this information about quantum numbers, energy values into as little space as possible?

Comment: There are a couple of issues here. First, there are different scales or the intrinsic effects. The principle splitting, fine structure and hyper fine structure occurs at very different scales, so showing all three on a single diagram would require very high resolution. Move over, the size of the Zeeman split (to chose one of your examples) depends on the applied magnetic field, so it is not a property of the atom alone.

Comment: In the meantime I already had thought of the magnetic field dependency of the Zeeman effect, guess you can't have everything. However, I'm not that interested in a completely accurate energy scale, but rather an indication of whether a certain level is shifted lower or higher.